# Вывод номера первого и последнего элементов массива

Tags: java

Дан целочисленный массив `A` размера `10`. Вывести номер первого и
последнего из тех его элементов `A[i]`, которые удовлетворяют двойному
неравенству: `A[1] < A[i] < A[10]`. Если таких элементов нет, то вывести 0.

Comment: На стрелочке плюсования есть подсказка - `вопрос отражает стремление разобраться, он понятен и несёт пользу`. Видимо, тем, кто это плюсует, достаточно `он понятен`?

Answer (score 1):

Индексы элементов в массиве начинаются с нуля `0`, а не с единицы `1`. Немного изменил условие задачи:

```java
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 234, 32, 23, 1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 22};

int first = -1;
int last = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[0] < arr[i] && arr[i] < arr[arr.length - 1])
        if (first == -1)
            first = i;
        else
            last = i;
```

Вывод:

```java
System.out.println("first: " + first + "; last: " + last);

// first: 6; last: 8
```

Comment: `arr[arr.length - 1]`